# why textbox onchange event to call javascriptfunction not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, textbox, onchange

My asp controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server" width="54%" onchange="return info();">      </asp:TextBox>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrNo" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

My javascript function:

```
function info() {  

var ss = document.getElementById(hdn);   
 var ss1 = document.getElementById(ddlrNo);
  var str = ss.value    
 var arr = str.split("~");
 alert(arr[0])
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    ss1.selectedIndex = 0
    ss1.options[0].text = arr[0];
}
}
```

I have a textbox on which i have to call javascript function,to get value from hidden field to populate dropdown value based on that hidden filed.

but it is not working what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

there are some things incorrect in the code
first `document.getElementById(hdn);` should be used in single or double quotes e.g.

```
document.getElementById("hdn");
```

same is the case with next line as well
then `ss1.options[0].text` this is incorrect as well
`.value` is more appropriate when accessing drop down list in javascript

Comment: If i am trying to get the value through "" then showing null in alert alert(document.getElementById("hdn"))

Comment: thats because arr[0] has nothing to show, u need more to understand about how do to do things in javascript, perhaps u would better use .getElementById("txtCustomer") in place of hdn

Comment: For other controls alert message showing OBJECTHTMLINPUTELEMENT. Nd arr[0] is written later in the js code,from the begining i am giving the alert

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server" width="54%" onblur="javascript:info()"/>
```